# talib error for calling talib functions

Tags: python, numpy

> File "SCTR.py", line 53, in 
>       ppoHist=ta.PPO(StockData['Last'],12,26)
>   TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)

please check this code and error i have mentioned above is reflecting after compilation.i am completely clueless at this point.

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO 
import certifi
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import talib as ta
from talib import MA_Type

url1 = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty_Alpha_Index.csv'
def datainpy(url):

    headers = { 'Accept' : '*/*',
                'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
                'Refers' : 'http://www.nseindia.com',
                'Connection' : 'keep-alive'
              }

    getContents = requests.get(url,headers=headers).content
    symbol_list=pd.read_csv(BytesIO(getContents))

    print(symbol_list.head())

    for eachSymbol in symbol_list['Symbol'][1:8]:
        stock = get_history(symbol = eachSymbol,
                            start = date(2016,3,20),
                            end = date(2016,3,30))
        stock.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
        stock.drop(stock.columns[[0,1,2,7,8,10,11,12,13]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        print (stock.head())
        print(stock.head())
        stock.index=pd.to_datetime(stock.index)
        #stock.to_csv('./HistoricalData//' + eachSymbol + '.csv' , date_format='%Y%m%d')
            return stock;



StockData=datainpy(url=url1)   
print(StockData.head())
type(StockData)
ppoHist=ta.PPO(StockData['Last'],12,26)
print(ppoHist.head())
```

I want basically to generate SCTR(Stock Chart Technical Rank) ie. PPO , DMA(200) , RSI etc. in one csv for 'eachSymbol'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing a pandas `Series` object to `ta.PPO` but it expects a numpy array.  Try

```
ppoHist = ta.PPO(StockData['Last'].values, 12, 26)
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself.  I don't have `talib` installed, and I can't answer any questions about it.)

Comment: can you please revert me how to find the slope of that ppo histogram ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO 
import certifi
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import talib as ta
from talib import MA_Type

#Long-Term Indicators (weighting)

#  * Percent above/below 200-day EMA (30%)
#  * 125-Day Rate-of-Change (30%)

#Medium-Term Indicators (weighting)

#  * Percent above/below 50-day EMA (15%)
#  * 20-day Rate-of-Change (15%)

# Short-Term Indicators (weighting)

#  * 3-day slope of PPO-Histogram (5%)
#  * 14-day RSI (5%)

url1 = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty_Alpha_Index.csv'
def datainpy(url):

    headers = { 'Accept' : '*/*',
                'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
                'Refers' : 'http://www.nseindia.com',
                'Connection' : 'keep-alive'
              }

    getContents = requests.get(url,headers=headers).content
    symbol_list=pd.read_csv(BytesIO(getContents))

    print(symbol_list.head())

    for eachSymbol in symbol_list['Symbol']:
        stock = get_history(symbol = eachSymbol,
                            start = date(2000,3,20),
                            end = date(2016,3,30))
        stock.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
        stock.drop(stock.columns[[0,1,2,7,8,10,11,12,13]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
        print (stock.head())
        print(stock.head())
        stock.index=pd.to_datetime(stock.index)
        #stock.to_csv('./HistoricalData//' + eachSymbol + '.csv' , date_format='%Y%m%d')
            return stock;



StockData=datainpy(url=url1)   
print(StockData.head())
type(StockData)
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

ppoHist=ta.PPO(StockData['Last'].values,12,26)

RSI14=ta.RSI(StockData['Last'].values,14)

DMA200=ta.SMA(StockData['Last'].values,200)

EMA50=ta.EMA(StockData['Last'].values,14)

ROC125=ta.ROC(StockData['Last'].values,125)

ROC20=ta.ROC(StockData['Last'].values,14)

weightPctDiffOfEMA50=(((StockData['Last'].values-EMA50)*100)/StockData['Last'].values)*15

weightPctDiffOfDMA200=(((StockData['Last'].values-DMA200)*100)/StockData['Last'].values)*30

weightROC125=ROC125*30

weightROC20=ROC20*15

weightRSI14=RSI14*5

weightppoHist=ppoHist*5
print(weightppoHist)
SCTR=(weightPctDiffOfDMA200+weightPctDiffOfEMA50+weightROC125+weightROC20+weightppoHist+weightRSI14)/100

print(SCTR)
```

i am little bit confused with the output but this is the one that would be mentioned here. [SCTR(Stock Chart Technical)](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:sctr). please provide better solution if any.